# Creating a custom table like excel sheets

Tags: html

I am making a custom table like this [Refrence1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6i0X.jpg).

I have used 'Table-striped' class, & td, tr, th.

The problem i am facing is [Reference2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ1zI.png)

In th i am creating almost 58 headings. And in image it can been seen clearly how it is going.

Help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had that problem a while ago.
Re-Check your div starting & closing. And Check that you are using class 'Table-Striped' on the right div.
Hope that helps.

Comment: I re-checked my quote. And i was literally making mistake. Thanks man!